# Unity: import video file without using a VideoPlayer

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm trying to load an .mp4 video file at runtime via script in order to have frame textures used by a shader. I have absolutely no need for video playback, thus I am looking for a way to load the video without instantiating a `VideoPlayer` component. Is this possible?

Unity docs only explain how to load videos using `VideoPlayer` like so

```
VideoPlayer vp = new VideoPlayer();
vp.url = Application.streamingAssetsPath + "/test-vid.mp4";
```

How do I simply load an mp4 for "backend" use in Unity?

Comment: well you could arguably read the binary in i guess but, how you gonna extract frames without some form of player

Comment: Right. It seems a little silly that VideoClip can't be utilized independently of VideoPlayer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't get around the VideoPlayer component but it's not so bad when using the [`VideoRenderMode.APIOnly`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Video.VideoRenderMode.html) property as it's telling the VideoPlayer that the video is not to be rendered anywhere.

```
VideoPlayer vp = gameObject.AddComponent<UnityEngine.Video.VideoPlayer>();

// Don't use the url property to load a video because then the VideoPlayer.clip property will remain null
//vp.url = Application.streamingAssetsPath + "/test-vid.mp4";

// Instead, load vid directly to VideoClip 
vc = Resources.Load<VideoClip>("test-vid");
vp.clip = vc;

// Tell it not to render anywhere
vp.renderMode = VideoRenderMode.APIOnly;

// Now you can access frame content-- see here for details on getting frame data: https://forum.unity.com/threads/how-to-extract-frames-from-a-video.853687/
```